# How can I pipe in a script through standard input as an argument to an executable

Tags: c#

I have an executable (purchased tool) that accepts it's own form of scripting language.  I'd like to wrap that executable with our own code to improve functionality.

Is there an accepted way to do this in C#, other than to create a temporary script file and pass that as an argument?

Currently I'm trying something like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "PathToExe";    
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;

using (System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi))
{
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter stdin = p.StandardInput)
    {
        stdin.Write("script line one");
        stdin.Write("script line two");
        stdin.Flush();

    }

    p.WaitForExit(10000);
}
```

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Code is about right - you may want to explain what is the problem you have with the code... Note that if tool prints anything you need to read output, otherwise it will simply "hang" waiting for output to be consumed.

Comment: I will try to implement the reading portion.  The problem now is that nothing happens.  If I run the same command from command line (with physical script), it will process the command and output a file.  From the project it will just run and end, no file created.  The commands in the script vs. what I'm passing through standard in are the same.

Comment: Side note: to simplify debugging consider building test exe that simply reads input and writes to output (or file) and use that instead of the "tool".

Comment: It looks like the tool is complaining that there is no file.  Is there a way to "fake" a file with standard in? If that even makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
```

Before start the process and should work, test your self creating a project(console) and using Console.ReadLine()

Comment: I am doing that, but I neglected to include that in the code above.  My apologies!